# Newline in bst file

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm using natbib like so:

```
\usepackage[numbers,square,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

and using the `plainnat` bibliography:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

I have the following citation in my bibliography:
[image: Citation]

But I would like to format it like so:

```
M. Abadi, L. Cardelli, B. Pierce, and G. Plotkin.
Dynamic Typing in a Statically-typed Language.
In Proceedings of the 16th ACM SIGPLAN-SIGACT Symposium on Principles of Programming Languages, pages 213-227.
Cited on page 77.
```

(i.e., newlines after the author list and after the title)

I tried modifying my bst file like so:

```
FUNCTION {author.full}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.full.names write$ newline$ }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title write$ newline$ }
  if$
}
```

But this doesn't produce the expected output. Specifically, I get the following:

[image: Citation not fixed]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`newline$` just writes an end of line to the generated latex that typesets as a space, you want

```
"\\ " write$
```

to write a `\\`

Comment: Thanks! I had to do "\leavevmode\\ " write$ to avoid a bunch of "There is no line to end here" errors, but otherwise it works!

Comment: @MathiasVorreiterPedersen  hmm I assumed (from your example) that you were forcing a line break after some text but...

Comment: I ... I thought I was as well... But oh well